# Using delegates with non static methods [no picked answer]

Tags: delegates

I am pretty confident that I should be able to use a delegate with a non-static method, but the below is giving me an error:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private delegate void TestDelegate();
    TestDelegate testDelegate = new TestDelegate(MyMethod);

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

If I make MyMethod static, everything works fine. Was I simply wrong in thinking I could use a delegate with a non static method (I am sure I remember doing so in the past).

Comment: You can *use* a delegate with a non-static method, but it doesn't mean you can *initialize a field* this way.

Comment: OK, do I need to do something different when initializing an instance of the delegate?

Comment: Something different, like *assigning* to it in your class *constructor* instead of initializing.

Comment: Aah that works, so I just can't initialize it outside of the scope of a method, if it's not static?

Comment: Yep (and that's what the error message says)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I get that now, I misunderstood the context of the error message, if you post this as an answer I will mark it as such (because it's the answer), thanks

Answer (score 3):

Answering this as I had to 'show more comments' and do a double take before I realised what the actual answer was.

Error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

The solution is to initialise the delegate inside the constructor.

I couldn't actually find this in the C# Language Reference itself, and a lot of the stock examples are static methods.

i.e.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private delegate void TestDelegate();
    TestDelegate testDelegate;

    public TestClass()
    {
        testDelegate = new TestDelegate(MyMethod);
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 
TestDelegate testDelgate = MyMethod;

Comment: Same error, Resharper had faded the rest of the code out anyway.