# Using delegates with non static methods in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

Asking the same question as 
[Using delegates with non static methods [no picked answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860002/)
so as to bring a closure to it.

So I use @Adam Marshall's solution, it works, but as soon as I start using it, i.e., `Testit()`:

```
using System;

public class TestClass
{
    private delegate void TestDelegate();
    TestDelegate testDelegate;

    public TestClass()
    {
        testDelegate = new TestDelegate(MyMethod);
    }

    public static void Testit()
    {
        testDelegate();
    }

    private virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        TestClass.Testit();
    }
}
```

It started to give the followig Error:

> A object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

You can [test it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQ8k68) . 
How to fix it? (Please fix it if possible instead of directing me to other posts, I've read them but am not able to understand them) Thx.

Comment: I don't know how you'd get that error with this code. This is trying to use a non-static member from inside a static member which is not allowed. An instance is required to invoke an instance member. The fiddle produces an error saying that an instance is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either everything has to be static or everything has to be instance. You're getting in trouble because you are mixing and matching.

Everything static:

```
using System;

public class TestClass
{
    private delegate void TestDelegate();
    static TestDelegate testDelegate;    //<-- static

    static TestClass()                   //<-- static
    {
        testDelegate = new TestDelegate(MyMethod);
    }

    public static void Testit()
    {
        testDelegate();
    }

    private static void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        TestClass.Testit();
    }
}
```

Everything instanced:

```
using System;

public class TestClass
{
    private delegate void TestDelegate();
    TestDelegate testDelegate;

    public TestClass()
    {
        testDelegate = new TestDelegate(MyMethod);
    }

    public void Testit()   
    {
        testDelegate();
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var t = new TestClass();
        t.Testit();   //<-- non-static
    }
}
```

Output (same in both examples):

```
Hello World
Foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use action C# internal delegate. This way you do not have specify the delegate. Then in your static method you could new up your object.

```
using System;

public class TestClass
{

    Action testDelegate;

    public TestClass()
    {
        testDelegate = new Action(MyMethod);
    }

    public static void Testit()
    {
        TestClass ts = new TestClass();
        ts.testDelegate();
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foobar");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        TestClass.Testit();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
Foobar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StuartSmith, I picked the other only because that is one I can understand (I don't know `Action`)